# Use append in Backbone View Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, append

```
 $el.find(".detail").append("<div class='noImageDetail'>teest</div>");
```

But not working. Checked in devtools, not found any bug. How can I use `append` in Backbone? Also, how can I use if - else?

Comment: Is that `$el` really `this.$el` in a view? If not, what is it? Are you sure it has a `.detail` inside it? Can you provide enough code to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any errors on your code as it is, now you need to make sure that exists something inside of your "el" with the "detail" class, example

HTML

```
<div id="book">
    <div class="detail">Book:</div>    
</div>
```

JS

```
var BookView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#book',

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.find(".detail").append("<div class='noImageDetail'>teest</div>");
    }
});


var bookView = new BookView();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this.$el.find('selector')` you could also use `this.$('selector')` which will save you some keystrokes since it's basically and alias to `this.$el.find`

I wrote an example in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ka0dEVWF94McDXHmEYb6?p=preview)

The if - else is basic JavaScript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else